# iOS - when SKView Controller added as Parent to normal ViewController buttons not working on Child Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, skview

I have iOS application developed with around 8 ViewControllers & it's working fine. I want to add SKView on top of entire app & all viewController, so I did following

- I created a ParentController & added SkView in to it

a

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
// Configure the SKView
SKView * skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
skView.allowsTransparency = YES;
skView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:skView];
[self.view addSubview:skView];
// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [MySKScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];}
```

Then

- I inherited this ParentController in other ViewController like MenuController
  as follows

  ```
   @interface MenuViewController : ParentViewController {}
  ```

Now when I click on button in menuController they are not receiving any touch, they are not getting clicked.

I want to use entire screen of SKView for moving around animated object with physics & I want that object to be available on all the screens, but at the same time basic functionality of the other viewControllers should work as it is.

you can say of playing minigame in ios application developed on SKView.
This is my first attempt of using SKView in iOS application & I am relatively new to iOS application development, any guidance or help will be very useful.

Comment: I spend lot of time working around this issue but I don't think there is any way to make it happen. I come to conclusion that it's not practically possible.